# PhpStorm false inspection error by using self type hint

Tags: phpstorm

the inspector in PhpStorm gives me an error even though the code is valid

```
interface PhoneInterface
{
    public function add(): self;
}

trait PhoneTrait
{
    public function add(): self
    {
        return $this;
    }
}

class A implements PhoneInterface
{
    use PhoneTrait;
}

var_dump(new A());
```

I get the error:

> "Declaration of 'PhoneTrait->add()' must be compatible with 'PhoneInterface->add()'"

But since PHP 7.4 this is valid. In the "Settings -> PHP level" I tried 7.4 and 8.0 but both gives me an error.

The error goes away if I remove the `:self` typehint.
The same code works here https://3v4l.org/SJCf2 and on my Server.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [corner case](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-57097) that hasn't been fixed along with the [general case](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-53288).